# socket.io for a simple chat application

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am making a simple chat application which has rooms and users join the room and chat. I don't have any authentication system so the users are random. I send the room id which I store in mongodb for users to perform join or leave room.  My problem is if I change the room in one browser the room chages in other browser.
Both the browsers which i open reflect same changes. I guess I am wrong, can someone help me with how to set this up.

```
   var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('socket', function(){
    return io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
});
myApp.controller('controller', function($scope, $http, $timeout, socket){
    $scope.rooms = [];
    $scope.messages = [];
    $scope.name;
    $scope.roomId ;
    socket.emit('get Rooms', {});
    socket.on('got rooms', function(data) {
        $scope.rooms = data.rooms;
        $scope.$digest();
    });
   $scope.addRoom = function() {
       socket.emit('add Rooms', {roomName : $scope.roomName});
   };
   $scope.changeRoom = function(id) {
       console.log(id);
       socket.emit('change Room',  $scope.roomId, id);

       socket.on('room changed', function(data) {
           $scope.roomId = data._id;

           socket.emit('sent Msg', $scope.roomId);
           socket.on('get Msg', function(data) {
               $scope.messages = data;
               $scope.$digest();
           });

       });
   };
// Adding Users name for first time
    $scope.addName = function(name) {
     $scope.name = name;
        socket.emit('user joined', name);
        socket.on('default group', function(data) {
           $scope.roomId = data._id;

            socket.emit('sent Msg', $scope.roomId);
            socket.on('get Msg', function(data) {
                $scope.messages = data;
                $scope.$digest();
            });
        })
   };
    $scope.sendMessage = function(msg) {
       socket.emit('send msg', msg, $scope.name,  $scope.roomId);
        socket.on('get Msg', function(data) {
            $scope.$digest();
        });
   };



});
```

My nodeJs code.

```
    io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    var roomsNow =[];
    var users = [];
    socket.on('get Rooms', function(data){
        Room.findAllRooms(function(err, doc){
            if(err)
            res.sendStatus(500);
            else if(doc){
                _.each(doc, function(data){
                    roomsNow.push(data)
                });
                io.sockets.emit('got rooms', {rooms: roomsNow});
            }
        });
    });
  socket.on('change Room', function(oldRoom, newRoom){
        socket.leave(oldRoom);
        socket.join(newRoom);
        io.sockets.emit('room changed', newRoom);

    });
```

Comment: that is what socket join will do..all connections from same browser will treat as same user so all events will be distributed to all tabs.. can you share client side code also so that I can help you..

Comment: ok I have opened two browsers one in incognito mode so when i change room in one browser the room is changed in other browser as well so is this wrong, if its wrong what sould i do can you tell me.

Comment: if you have opened in incognito.. then it should work let me check and update..

Comment: Oop! issue with join.. you should do two things..  socket.join(newRoom); and  socket.join(res.sessionID); and while emit we should to io.to(res.sessionID).emit('room changed', newRoom);

Comment: can i have an alternate solution  to session.id may be use the room id or something, is session important

Comment: you can create random string at client side (May be current time-stamp) and pass to server so that to io.to(req.param('uniqueId')).emit('room changed', newRoom);